# Is a domain needed for app bundle ID to submit to app store?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I do not want to have to purchase a domain but would like to submit an app I have developed to the App Store. I was wondering if the app bundle ID had to include a reverse domain owned by you (the developer) or if just any unique string would work. I have tried looking on google etc. but there is no obvious answer. Alternatively, if the bundle ID did have to be a reverse domain, would websiteName.weebly.com be written as com.weebly.websiteName or is that not an option.

Thanks.

Comment: just any unique string would work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The domain you need to put for the app like `com.company.awesomeapp` is the bundle identifier for the app. You do not need to have the `company.com` domain.

---

> A bundle ID or bundle identifier uniquely identifies an application in Apple's ecosystem. This means that no two applications can have the same bundle identifier. To avoid conflicts, Apple encourages developers to use reverse domain name notation for choosing an application's bundle identifier.

If you want more information, read [What Are App IDs and Bundle Identifiers](https://cocoacasts.com/what-are-app-ids-and-bundle-identifiers/).

Comment: Is this true even when submitting to the App Store?

Comment: Yes, I don't know if com.wix is already used by Wix or someone else but the domain doesn't need to be "real". I have an app with com.pol.myapp on the appstore and I don't have the pol.com @BenR.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is really helpful. This is my first time submitting an app so the help is really appreciated. BTW, I tried to upvote your answer because this is so helpful but it won't let me (less than 15 reputation ) @Pol

Answer (score 1):

Your purchased domain name is going to always be unique. That's why apple suggests the bundle ID in reverse just to make sure that your bundle Id don't clash with other app's bundle ID. Otherwise any unique string will work as a bundle ID.

Comment: Thank you this really helps

Answer (score 0):

While submitting the app to the App Store. You have to enter the support URL.

Comment: But for this I could just use a free company.wix.com address?

Comment: It will work.  Need two URL  Contact Us and Support URL